# Enable credentials in puckel/docker-airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am using [puckel/docker-airflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/puckel/docker-airflow/dockerfile) to deploy airflow. 
Currently, the webserver is not asking for any credentials to login.
How can I add a user to it? Maybe i have to add some environment variable in docker-compose.yml, but i am unable to find it. The docker-compose file is [here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own airflow.cfg (Assume it is stored in `./config/airflow.cfg`) and follow [Airflow Security Guide](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html) to define credential.

Then, mount your config file to docker container can help you, add `./config/airflow.cfg:/usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg` to your `webserver` docker compose

Example:

```
volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./config/airflow.cfg:/usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.