# How to create/Enable Password login for Puckel/docker-airflow

Tags: docker, airflow

I have tried [Enable credentials in puckel/docker-airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781889/enable-credentials-in-puckel-docker-airflow)
and getting the Login page, however, it is not accepting any id or password.

Followed the following steps too:

1. airflow initdb and upgrade db
2. airflow create user ....

But, no luck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not related - but why not use official image? There's a really nice (how to start guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

Comment: I tried the following steps, but got an error while running the docker-compose.
(ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "x-airflow-common". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, secrets, configs, and extensions starting with "x-".)



I am new to airflow, trying to find a step by step way to enable credential login from ubuntu server

Comment: This is a docker issue. As per the guide: "Older versions of docker-compose do not support all features required by docker-compose.yaml file, so double check that it meets the minimum version requirements." Try upgrading your docker-compose